# How to pass Variable to Views in Laravel Controller

Tags: php, controller, laravel-5

I have a controller in Laravel 5.0 like this-

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Http\Requests;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

    class CustomersController extends CustomerLayoutController
    {
        public function getDashboard()
        {
            return $this->view('layouts.customer.dashboard', []);
        }

        public function getTest()
        {
            return $this->view('layouts.admin.webinar', ['qustions' => DB::table('qustions')->get()]);
        }
    }
```

So, I want to pass **DB::table('qustions')->get()** as a parameter to my views, but I m getting error.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: What error are you getting? It's pretty important to know that

Comment: FatalErrorException in CustomersController.php line 18:
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\DB' not found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting an error because Laravel is searching the class is the wrong namespace (it's "appending" the class to the current class's namespace, if you note).

You either import the DB class with the `use` keywords:

```
 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 use App\Http\Requests;
 use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
 use DB;
```

or let it know that `DB` resides in the "global" application namespace, so call it with a backslash:

```
return $this->view('layouts.admin.webinar', ['questions' => \DB::table('qustions')->get()]);
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me

Comment: It's worth mentioning that inside the `config/app.php` resides a key `aliases` which will map `'DB' => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB'`.